# Set my USB Mass storage Device Read-only for WINDOWS

Tags: c#

Please some one suggest me how can I achieve this first point

1. No one must be allowed to remove or edit the files or folders in Storage drive via windows or console interface or any other
2. Only from my application(c# app or any) It should be possible to Write/delete folder/file functionality must support
3. Only read permission provided, as regular functionality default to everyone who access drive.

Point. In case if I am setting to write permission of device, In case user unplug when it set to write permission then it should behave as readonly when he plugs back [in case any solution like setting to disk format]

Thanks,
Anand L

Comment: So you only want to know how to do the "first point", that is #1 on your list, but none of the others? Also, what you're asking isn't possible, there's *always* a way to get around this stuff... you can only make it harder to do it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff BridgMan, 
 I want all 3 points to achieve actually.

Comment: I need similar to ITunes functionality like Iphone or I devices connectivity with PC, It will not allow you to drop anything in storage directly instead we have to do it via - Itnues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not ever accomplish all three goals, you do this a limited sense though [as described here](http://www.pacebutler.com/blog/how-to-make-usb-storage-device-read-only/)

Basically the option boil down to having admin admin priv and setting registries entry accordingly (or going through the UI to do the same thing) or 3rd party software to make USB device read only.

ADDED

Probably should have mentioned that some flash drives have a "write-protect" switch on the device -- which is really the only trust-worthy way to write-protect a drive, it is of course useless as a security feature that you desire

ADDED

There is a volume lock function, never used it, the [method is DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) you need to use [FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364575(v=vs.85).aspx) to lock the volume. Not sure how if helps you though.

Comment: The write-protect switch wouldn't be helpful though from the ability to edit what's on the drive solely from the program though, would it?

Comment: Can I achieve from this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364399(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I will take it further.. thanks for all support

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set the read-only attribute on a file:

   ```
   File.SetAttributes("C:\\myFile.txt", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
   ```

   But this is not a security mechanism (to quote another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252530/945456)), so it won't really accomplish what you want. For example, I could launch the command prompt and type `del /F file.txt` and it will happily delete a read-only file for me.
2. In your application you can can use the various methods on the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to accomplish what you need in regards to this point (e.g. [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
3. You'll need to ensure you set the read-only attribute when you create your file.